# Calling JLabel from method

Tags: java, arrays, swing, methods

I'm currently following a tutorial on how to make a guessing game gui app. I don't understand the following instruction though. **Create each JLabel of lblBoard by calling the overloaded constructor and setting the text to "" (empty string) and it's alignment to center**

any help would be greatly appreciated

here is my code so far:

```
package assignment.pkg19;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Object;

public class Assignment19 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

Container content = this.getContentPane(); 

//arrays
    JLabel lblBoard [] = new JLabel[16]; 
     int nums [] = new int[16];

     //variables
     int firstChoice = -1;
     int tries = 0;

     //interface
     JButton btnGame = new JButton("New Game");
     JLabel lblTries = new JLabel("0"); 
     JPanel pnlControls = new JPanel();
     JPanel pnlBoard = new JPanel();
     String lblFirst;
     public void createLabels()
     {
         pnlBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4, 5, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)  
        {
            //call jlabel
            lblBoard.setOpaque(true);



        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: `new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTRE);`. I'd encourage you to make use of the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) and [tutorials]([How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)) first

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. Looking at my code, which overloaded constructor are the instructions referring to? I ask this because the next instruction is to set each JLabel to opaque, but when I do lblBoard.setOpaque(true); I get an error

Comment: `lblBoard` is an array, you need to provide an index to the element you want to change `lblBoard[i].setOpaue(true);`

Comment: *"I get an error"* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is the function that is called when you create a new Object of a Class. (In our case, JLabel is the class), try this:

```
for(int index=0;index<lblBoard.lenght;i++){
        lblBoard[index] = new JLabel(""); 
        //We create a new JLabel object without text in the array of JLabels lblBoard.
}
```